# Передать параметр в цикл for

Tags: циклы, bash

Как изменить этот скрипт, что бы при запуске с параметром "6", скрипт выдавал бы числа  от 6 до 20. Понимаю что надо зделать что-то с этим куском кода **`seq 1 20;`** ?

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 20`;

do
  sleep 1
  echo $i 
done
```

Comment: Не пойму как соеденить команду. Нужно что-то типа  
'seq ' + $param1 + '20'

Comment: Вау! Как все просто!!! Это сработало...

Comment: @jmu преобразуйте комментарий в ответ, а @hooko примите его как правильный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте: seq $1 20